# How to get <s:button> functionality in Struts2?

Tags: javascript, struts2

```
<s:form action="XYZ" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="sno" />
    <s:textarea name="t" rows="2" cols="4" />

    <!-- Here i want a button lets say -->
    <s:button value="GET TEXT" />

    <!--
        which executes other action (not "XYZ" ) and fill the textarea based on the serial no value(sno). 
    -->

    <s:submit  value="submit" />
</s:form>
```

---

**Table**

sno    text

---

1     "hsdjhjjsh"
 2     "jsdjh hj kjskjdhj"

When submit the form it should insert a new row. `Action "XYZ"` does that.
But when i give existing sno lets say "1" and onclick `GET TEXT` button it should not submit form it but should call other action which will fill the textarea with `hsdjhjjsh`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please reformat and post your original code?

Comment: Edited my question,now it is clear.

Comment: I meant, can you post your actual HTML code, and then format it by pressing the code button that looks like { }?

Comment: I have to write code using struts tags.So i posted like that.

Comment: I just need <input type="button"> kind of thing in struts 2

Comment: Don't know what `<s:button>` tag renders to in HTML but can you not just replace it with `<input type="button">` if that's what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use plain HTML: input type button?

If you don't want to submit, it probably does not need any struts functionality.

Comment: I want to use value from struts iterator which should be passed to onclick javascript function